# Jquery syntax error on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to submit a form which has had fields added via jquery by the user, the issues is submitting it the usual way misses these user defined fields out. I am using the submit function instead in jquery, but I am receiving errors. Have I done something wrong below?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        //prevent the default submithandling
        e.preventDefault();

        //alert(1);
        //send the data of \'this\' (the matched form) to yourURL
        $('processme.php', $(this).serialize()).submit;
    });
});
```

I tried he post function before, but because it doesnt actually go to the page on post it caused a 500 server error, this would work but it shoes a syntax error on the serialised data in firebug console.

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

This is the exact error "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: details1=&userval=2
/jquery-1.9.1.js
Line 4421
throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );"

Here is the code used to add the new input fields:

```
function addRow(){
 $('#tbl1').find('tbody:last').after('<tr><td>User Defined</td><td><input name="userdef[]" value="" type="text"></td>/td></tr>');
}
```

P.S The processme.php has a forwarder builtin which depends on the validation response. So post needs to be submitted to the processme.php.

PHp code:

```
 print_r($_POST);
 print_r($_POST("userdef")); echo "<br/>";
        foreach ($_POST("userdef") as $key=>$val) {
            echo $key." - ".$val.", ";
        }
        exit()
```

Output:

```
  Array ( [userdef] => Array ( [1] => 11111 ) [userval] => Array ( [0] => ) )
```

Comment: what is this line supposed to do? `$(\'processme.php\', $(this).serialize())`. Also show code that adds the new input fields...do they all have `name`?  No `name` = No submit

Comment: Why are you having \ before every quotation?

Comment: just change `\'` to `'` or `"`

Comment: Its not do with the escapes, thats because its being built in a php file

Comment: HI Charlietti, yes the new fields all have the same name, its supposed to submit the form including the newly added fields

Comment: What are the errors that are logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way would be to use the built in submit function.

My guess is that the fields are either not being added to the form properly or they are not being named properly.

If you could post the code for that section we may be able to get this working.

Try this, and see if the original submit stuff works properly

```
var count = 0;
function addRow(){
    count++;
    $('#tbl1').find('tbody:last').after('<tr><td>User Defined</td><td><input         name="userdef['+count+']" value="" type="text"></td>/td></tr>');
}



foreach ( $_POST['userdef'] as $key => $val){
    echo $key . ' = ' . $val . '\n'; 
}
```

Comment: Ok, So I have done this. I can see the multi dimensional array when I print_r($_POST), but I can't see anything when I try loop through the $_POST['userdef'].. any ideas?

Comment: Array ( [userdef] => Array ( [1] => 11111 ) [userval] => Array ( [0] => ) )

Comment: Can you add the print_r in a code block to the original post so i can see it all formatted and pretty, also the code that loops through it could be helpful

Comment: Anytime, i do that all the time!!

Comment: Damn thats annoying, so far in. Over complicated the simplest of fixes!!! I feel like a pratt. Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$('#form').on('submit',function() {

    var url = "processme.php";

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: The issue is, the processme.php has a forwarder builtin which depends on the validation response. So this way would not work.

Comment: If you can also share your php code also, then we can figure it out easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think `$('processme.php', $(this).serialize()).submit` is the issue. You mean to do `$.get` and the `.submit` is useless.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        //prevent the default submithandling
        e.preventDefault();

        //alert(1);
        //send the data of \'this\' (the matched form) to yourURL
        $.get('processme.php', $(this).serialize());
    });
});
```